# Why is GorillaMux not allowing me to pass in a URL as a parameter?

Tags: rest, http, go, backend, gorilla

I'm building a URL shortener API and I'm trying to pass a URL into a function using GorillaMux. The route handler is like so:

```
router.HandleFunc("/new/{url}", createURL)
```

The only thing is, if I pass in: https://www.google.com (as in localhost:8080/new/https://www.google.com) then it responds with `404 page not found` and the URL is changed to https:/www.google.com.

I've tried adding a regexp pattern in with the {url} bit like so: {url:[a-zA-Z0-9/]+} but that didn't seem to work and seems a bit overkill since I'm checking the url is correct elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You need to encode it so that the slash in the parameter was not confused as a part of the url:

```
localhost:8080/new/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
```

Comment: How would one encode it before its passed to the function `createURL`?

Comment: @AndyMorgan what do you exactly mean? It is the client's responsibility to do that

Comment: I don't know what you mean by it's the client's responsibility to do that. I'll need to do it. I won't have a form on a page that will encode the URL. The site is `localhost:8080` and then the user passes in the URL to be shortened as `localhost:8080/new/https://www.example.com`.

Comment: The URL shortener is meant to be functionally similar to this: https://little-url.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @AndyMorgan it's not gorilla mux that requires it, but the URL RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3 Whoever generates your urls must specify them properly encoded.

Comment: I'm totally in agreement that that would be one way of doing it, where the client (or the frontend) passes in an encoded url, it would certainly solve my problem. But, I'm not doing it that way, the user needs to pass in the url to be shortened unencoded. I do appreciate your answer to my question, that was helpful, but my next question was: How would one encode it before its passed to the function? I'm trying to figure out how to do that in my main.go file.

Comment: I did see QueryEscape, but how would one encode it before its passed to the function using QueryEscape?

Comment: Before "what" is passed to "what" function?

Comment: Before the url is passed to the function `createURL`. So, this is my code: `router.HandleFunc("/new/{url}", createURL)`, could I encode the url before it is passed to the function, `createURL` using QueryEscape?

Comment: You cannot. By the moment the url reaches your code it's already broken. The **properly encoded url** must be generated by whoever makes a request. So if you type the URL manually in your browser - you must manually type the properly encoded url.