# How do I pass a URL as a parameter in a Golang route?

Tags: http, url, go, routes, gorilla

I'm trying to pass a URL as a parameter in Golang, and I haven't been able to find a solution in all of the tutorials I've looked at. The problem is that I can only get the url to return minus a crucial forward slash.

My handler looks like this:

```
router.HandleFunc("/new/{url}", createURL)
```

So the request would look like:

```
www.myapp.heroku.com/new/https://www.google.com
```

However, the url that I results is missing a slash:

```
http:/www.google.com
```

I sure it's probably got something to do with RFC3986, but is there a way to pass in the url as it is?

Comment: Pass it in a query param and urlencode it. Because depending on what mux you use to parse that, might interpret that differently. Eg.: '?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F'

Comment: @BogdanIulianBursuc The only thing is the user will just be passing in the url after the /new parameter. So, they'd first go to `www.myapp.heroku.com` then get an instruction to pass the url in after /new like so: `www.myapp.heroku.com/new/https://www.google.com`. I don't know how to pass it in a query param unfortunately.

Comment: It should still be URL-encoded. The example URLs given are not valid URLs, so you'll get no guarantees they'll work correctly with any parser.

Comment: @Adrian True. And depends also if you have a proxy server in between. Might parse it differently also.

Comment: @BogdanIulianBursuc Just to clarify, the urls can't be passed in a query param and then parsed. The URLs are passed in like in this app: https://little-url.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I'm little bit confused, you're building server (which parse the URL) or client (pass URL) with golang? For server side, you need to implement your own `Handler` or `ServeMux`, since the default handler will remove the '//' part and give response `301` (Moved Permanently) to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular behavior in Gorilla Mux can be changed by setting SkipClean to **true**.

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.SkipClean(true)
router.HandleFunc("/new/", index)
router.HandleFunc("/", index)
http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, router)
```

The relevant documentation can be found [here](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Router.SkipClean).

Answer (score 2):

After reading [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626030/why-is-gorillamux-not-allowing-me-to-pass-in-a-url-as-a-parameter), I understand what do you mean. Implement a kind of URL re-writer before URL goes to `gorilla/mux`. The function will look like:

```
func Rewriter(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        //Simple URL rewriter. Rewrite if it's started with API path
        pathReq := r.RequestURI
        if strings.HasPrefix(pathReq, "/new/") {
            //Use url.QueryEscape for pre go1.8
            pe := url.PathEscape(strings.TrimLeft(pathReq, "/new/"))
            r.URL.Path = "/new/" + pe
            r.URL.RawQuery = ""
        }

        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Wrap gorilla router when starting the http server:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()

// ... other handler
r.HandleFunc("/new/{original-url}", NewHandler)

//Wrap mux.Router using Rewriter
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", Rewriter(r)))
```

Then in your `URL shortener` handler, the original URL can be extracted using the following code:

```
func NewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    ou := vars["original-url"]
    //Use url.QueryUnascape for pre go1.8
    originalURL, err := url.PathUnescape(ou)

    //... other processing
}
```

IMHO, implementing `URL shortener` service like this is not recommended, mainly due to incorrect use of HTTP verbs. Any `GET` request should not leave side effect in server e.g. no record creation in database, etc.